# Worklight - Invocation of procedure 'StoredProcedure' failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am getting this error when I try to call procedure in mysql

`[ERROR   ] FWLSE0035E: Invocation of procedure 'StoredProcedure' failed. [project projectname] invalid type of element`

in my stored procedure i am creating table dynamically,
When I try `"Invoke Worklight Procedure"` from worklight studio it works well and create table, but when I run from webpage it gives me error

my calling procedure call is

```
WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
    procedure : 'createUserFormTable',
    parameters : ['table_name', ' (name VARCHAR(10), language VARCHAR(10));']
});
```

and in my SQL I tried both of these

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createUserFormTable(p_tbl VARCHAR(20), p_columns TEXT)
CREATE PROCEDURE createUserFormTable(p_tbl VARCHAR(20), p_columns VARCHAR(1000))
```

Note: It works and create table when I call from worklight studio.

Comment: I am able to resolve by adding .toString() in the 2nd parameter

I was creating variable in javasript like var param2 = ""; and then concat but surprisingly adapter was not considering it as a string, when I added param2.toString() in the end it worked well.

So All is well now,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to resolve by adding .toString() in the 2nd parameter I was creating variable in javasript like var param2 = ""; and then concat but surprisingly adapter was not considering it as a string, when I added param2.toString() in the end it worked well.